# Need help rounding the results of my column count to 2dp

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, rounding, percentage

I have the below query which gives the percentage of each service standard code out of 100

```
SELECT AchievedServiceStandardCode,
       count(AchievedServiceStandardCode)  as AchievedServiceStandardCode_count,
       count(AchievedServiceStandardCode) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from manifest) as delivery_percent
FROM manifest
Where AgencyID=1
group by AchievedServiceStandardCode
```

[Table Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mmP4.png)

The issue that I am having is that I cannot figure out how to round the results from my count, which are given in the delivery percent column. Ideally I need to round the results to 2dp.

Ideally my desired outcome should look like this instead of the table above

[Table desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mmP4.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016 or higher you could use [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) passing a ["P"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) as the format (2nd) parameter value. You would have to get rid of your multiplication by 100.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `round` function:

```
round(count(AchievedServiceStandardCode) * 100.0 / (select count(*) from manifest), 2)
    as delivery_percent
```